# Iterate over all elements in template in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have following template. How can I get access to all the elements inside the template? I tried using ViewChildren but it gives reference to only one element (I guess because no two elements are same and I am not using same directive/component inside the template)

```
template: `

 <div>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> </div>
 <div>Gender: <select  name="gender" >
    <option>Male(1)</option>
    <option>Female(2)</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div>About you: <textarea ></textarea></div>
 <div>Married: <input type="checkbox" /></div>      
  <div>
  Children:     
    <ng-container *ngFor = "let option of this.selectOptions">
    <input  type="radio" [id]="option" name="children" [value]=option [(ngModel)]="this.children"/> {{option}}
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <p > Some para</p>
  <p >Para with span <span>Inside span</span></p>

`
```

**Question 1 -** 
How can I get a collection of all elements in the template?

**Question 2 -** 
What would be the way to distinguish between the elements. I guess all the elements would be of type ElementRef.

Comment: There may be a more Angular-ish way to accomplish your goal. What are you trying to do that you need the collection of all elements in the template?

Comment: You can just inject `elementRef: ElementRef`

Comment: At this moment, just learning Angular. Was writing some code and realized I do not know how to get access to all elements. I can obviously use template ref variable but then I'll have to do it for all the individual elements.

Comment: but wouldn't `ElementRef` give reference to only one element? I thought that if I use `ViewChildren`, I can get a `QueryList` but that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

The idea with Angular is that you should never need to do this.

> There are very few circumstances where manipulating the DOM directly
>   is necessary.   Angular 2 provides a set of powerful, high-level APIs
>   like queries that one can use instead.
>   - http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

Comment: OK it's not recommended but it's not really the question there.